# helm install --name=mariadb ./mariadb --namespace=openstack is not running

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, kubernetes-helm

I am following the procedure on this page.

https://docs.openstack.org/openstack-helm/latest/install/developer/all-in-one.html

kubernetes-AIO install complete and running kubeadm.

But, mariadb chart install was failed.

(Status is Running -> Error -> CrashLoopbackOff-> Runing -> Error... loop)

so, I used this command to solve the problem.

> kubectl logs mariadb-0 --namespace openstack

The result is like this:

```html
+ CLUSTER_INIT_ARGS=
+ '[' '!' -d /var/lib/mysql/mysql ']'
+ CLUSTER_CONFIG_PATH=/etc/mysql/conf.d/10-cluster-config.cnf
+ MEMBERS=
++ seq 1 3
+ for i in '$(seq 1 ${MARIADB_REPLICAS})'
+ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
+ NUM=0
+ CANDIDATE_POD=mariadb-0.mariadb-discovery
+ '[' xmariadb-0.mariadb-discovery '!=' xmariadb-0.mariadb-discovery ']'
+ for i in '$(seq 1 ${MARIADB_REPLICAS})'
+ '[' 2 -eq 1 ']'
++ expr 2 - 1
+ NUM=1
+ CANDIDATE_POD=mariadb-1.mariadb-discovery
+ '[' xmariadb-1.mariadb-discovery '!=' xmariadb-0.mariadb-discovery ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ MEMBERS+=mariadb-1.mariadb-discovery:4567
+ for i in '$(seq 1 ${MARIADB_REPLICAS})'
+ '[' 3 -eq 1 ']'
++ expr 3 - 1
+ NUM=2
+ CANDIDATE_POD=mariadb-2.mariadb-discovery
+ '[' xmariadb-2.mariadb-discovery '!=' xmariadb-0.mariadb-discovery ']'
+ '[' -n mariadb-1.mariadb-discovery:4567 ']'
+ MEMBERS+=,
+ MEMBERS+=mariadb-2.mariadb-discovery:4567
+ echo 'Writing cluster config for mariadb-0 to /etc/mysql/conf.d/10-cluster-config.cnf'
+ cat
Writing cluster config for mariadb-0 to /etc/mysql/conf.d/10-cluster-config.cnf
Executing upstream docker-entrypoint.
+ echo 'Executing upstream docker-entrypoint.'
+ set +e
+ exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.23-MariaDB-1~jessie) starting as process 1 ...
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so'
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 25.3.20(r3703) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using hardware acceleration.
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1, safe_to_bootsrap: 1
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_dir = /var/lib/mysql/; base_host = 10.1.60.5; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; debug = no; evs.auto_evict = 0; evs.delay_margin = PT1S; evs.delayed_keep_period = PT30S; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 3; evs.send_window = 4; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 2; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /var/lib/mysql//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.recover = no; gcache.size = 128M; gcomm.thread_prio = ; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.listen_addr = tcp://0.0.0.0:4567; gmcast.segment = 0; gmcast.version = 0; pc.announce_tim
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: GCache history reset: old(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:0) -> new(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1)
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: -1, protocol version: -1
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_sst_grab()
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: protonet asio version 0
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: Using CRC-32C for message checksums.
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: gcomm thread scheduling priority set to other:0 
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Warning] WSREP: access file(/var/lib/mysql//gvwstate.dat) failed(No such file or directory)
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: restore pc from disk failed
2017-11-14  7:27:42 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
2017-11-14  7:28:10 139786759522240 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to resolve tcp://mariadb-1.mariadb-discovery:4567
2017-11-14  7:28:30 139786759522240 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to resolve tcp://mariadb-2.mariadb-discovery:4567
2017-11-14  7:28:30 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: (4d30eff1, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
2017-11-14  7:28:30 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: (4d30eff1, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
2017-11-14  7:28:30 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 0
2017-11-14  7:28:30 139786759522240 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'mariadb', peer 'mariadb-1.mariadb-discovery:4567,mariadb-2.mariadb-discovery:4567'
2017-11-14  7:28:30 139786759522240 [ERROR] WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 131: No address to connect (FATAL)
         at gcomm/src/gmcast.cpp:connect_precheck():282
2017-11-14  7:28:30 139786759522240 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():208: Failed to open backend connection: -131 (State not recoverable)
2017-11-14  7:28:30 139786759522240 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1404: Failed to open channel 'mariadb' at 'gcomm://mariadb-1.mariadb-discovery:4567,mariadb-2.mariadb-discovery:4567': -131 (State not recoverable)
2017-11-14  7:28:30 139786759522240 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: State not recoverable
2017-11-14  7:28:30 139786759522240 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://mariadb-1.mariadb-discovery:4567,mariadb-2.mariadb-discovery:4567) failed: 7
2017-11-14  7:28:30 139786759522240 [ERROR] Aborting
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that some packages are being filtered and thus the network discovery is not working. Maybe you the network configuration in your Openstack cluster does not allow service discovery communications.

Also, it could be that you set wrong anything in the chart values configuration. I advise you to check if it works in dev environments like Minikube or Kubernetes Sandbox. If it works in that environment, then there is definitely something wrong in the communication technology you used to configure `neutron`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I set up the physical network and reinstalled the AIO.
Then it works normally.